# VSTS: Search a library reference in all projects

Tags: azure-devops

I have a library and I want to search all the projects which have a reference to this library.

All projects are in master branch. We are using Git with VSTS.

Is there a way to search all the projects?

Comment: Have you looked at Code Search?

Comment: I checked the documentation but never user it. I guess code needs to be executed. If so, I don't have permission to do the same.

Comment: Code Search is a text based search with intelligent parsing of the programming language. It's an extension that you can easily install from the Marketplace (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-code-search) so you can always give it a try.

Comment: @WouterdeKort Thanks. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**Code Search**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-code-search) (as Wouter said) can make it efficient for you to quick search a reference through all the team project (or in a team project).

#### Search the library from all the repos in a team project:

Goto a team project code Tab (https://account.visualstudio.com/_git/project) -> input the keywords which you want to search.

[image]

Such as search `packages\Microsoft.Net`, it will list all the files which contain `packages\Microsoft.Net` in Code Tab. And you can also specify repo, branch, path etc.

[image]

#### Search the library from all the team projects of the VSTS account:

Goto VSTS home page (https://account.visualstudio.com/_projects)
 -> input the keywords you want to search.

[image]

If you also search `packages\Microsoft.Net`, then it will list all the related files from all the team projects. And you can also specify project, repo, branch and path etc.

[image]

And you can also refer the document [Search your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/search/code/code-search).